# What is the 8-byte extra memory comsuption by ptmalloc chunk?

Tags: linux, memory, malloc

I've read that ptmalloc needs at least 8 extra bytes for each chunk. And I made a demo to confirm it.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        void *a = malloc(1);
        printf("%p %d\n", a, malloc_usable_size(a));
        for (int i=0; i<32; i++) {
            printf("%02x ", *((unsigned char*)a+i));
        } printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
0x1afa010 24
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e1 0f 02 00 00 00 00 00 
0x1afa030 24
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c1 0f 02 00 00 00 00 00 
0x1afa050 24
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 a1 0f 02 00 00 00 00 00 
0x1afa070 24
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 81 0f 02 00 00 00 00 00
```

It does consume extra 8-byte memory for each chunk. But what is it? I failed to find the answer online.

I found the chunk struct in glibc source code, but it doesn't seem to match.

```c
struct malloc_chunk {

  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      mchunk_prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      mchunk_size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

  /* Only used for large blocks: pointer to next larger size.  */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};
```

Comment: There are different versions of `malloc()`. Obviously, your version differs from the version in the glibc source code.

Comment: I figure out the reason now. It's the size of next chunk. System alloced 33 pages of memory as a big chunk.